# Creating NSDictionary with keys that have multiple values

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I have a mutable array that contains `NSDictionary` dic1 objects,

each dictionary has a key called  `contactId`, more than one dictionary can have the same value for `contactId`.

What I want to do is to create an `NSDictionary` with unique `contactIds` as the keys and an array value that contains a list of all `NSDictionary` dic1 objects that have the value `contactId` equal to the key.

How can I do this?

My data looks like this:

```
**myArray**:[  **dic1** {contactId = x1 , name = name1 }, **dic2**{contactId = x2, name = 
name2 }, **dic3**{contactId = x1, name = name3} ]
```

I want it to become like this:

```
**NSDictionary**: { **x1**:[dic1, dic3], **x2**:[dic2] }
```

Comment: you can't have a dictionary with only value. It needs to have both, it's a type of data structure that is designed to looks like that and to behave accordingly.

Comment: @ant i believe you misunderstood my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use fast enumeration:

```
NSMutableDictionary *result = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (id obj in myArray)
{
    NSString *contactId = [obj objectForKey:@"contactId"];
    NSMutableSet *contacts = [result objectForKey:contactId];
    if (!contacts)
    {
        contacts = [NSMutableSet set]
        [result setObject:contacts forKey:contactId];
    }
    [contacts addObject:obj];
}
```

You could use blocks for no real added benefit:

```
__block NSMutableDictionary *result = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[myArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    NSString *contactId = [obj objectForKey:@"contactId"];
    NSMutableSet *contacts = [result objectForKey:contactId];
    if (!contacts)
    {
        contacts = [NSMutableSet set]
        [result setObject:contacts forKey:contactId];
    }
    [contacts addObject:obj];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the classic way?

```
NSMutableDictionary* Result;
NSEnumerator* Enumerator;
NSDictionary* Dict;
Result=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
Enumerator=[YourArray objectEnumerator];
while ((Dict=[Enumerator nextObject])!=nil)
{
   NSString* ContactID;
   NSMutableSet* Contacts;
   ContactID=[Dict objectForKey:@"contactID"];
   Contacts=[Result objectForKey:ContactID];
   if (Contacts==nil)
   {
      Contacts=[[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
      [Result setObject:Contacts forKey:ContactID];
      [Contacts release];
   }
   [Contacts addObject:Dict];
}
```

This should create a Result dictionary. I haven't tested (or even compiled) this, though.

Comment: Please follow coding conventions, and name your variables using `lowerCamelCase`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't actually expect stackoverflow coding conventions, so I never looked for them... :-(

Comment: @ChristianStieber -- They're standard C conventions, used by C coders everywhere (except in Microsoft, apparently).

Comment: @ChristianStieber: Have a look at Apple's example code. Objective-C code follows a very simple convention where variables and method names are in `lowerCamelCase` and classes are in `UpperCamelCase`. There are a few exceptions to the rule, but mostly this is the case. Using an `UpperCamelCase` variable name makes it difficult to distinguish whether the receiver is a class or an instance.